# Show that if a succession of vectors converges, then the numeric succession of the vectors also converges.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Show that if $\{v_n\}_n \subset H$, where H is a Hilbert space, and $\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n v_k\}_n$ converges, then the numeric succession $\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n ||v_k||_P\}_n$ converges as well. I know that the opposite happens, as you simply have to use the triangle inequality, but I don't know how to proof this, perhaps there is a theorem because I have tried with inequalities and failed, all help appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Is the norm $\|\cdot\|_P$ just the Hilbert space norm, or is it something different? If it's the Hilbert space norm, then this is not true in general (even in one dimension).

Comment: Is just the Hilbert space norm

Comment: In that case, take $H = \Bbb{R}$ (so $\|\cdot\|_P = | \cdot |$) and let $v_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Any series that is conditionally convergent will do. By definition, this means that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty v_k$ converges, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |v_k|$ does not.